# Access resource defined in theme and attrs.xml android

Tags: android, resources, attributes, themes, drawable

I have a scenario in which I want to set a `Drawable` depending upon the theme defined.

To explain this further, Here is what I have in code:

**\res\values\attrs.xml**

```
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="AppTheme">
        <attr name="homeIcon" format="reference" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

**res\values\styles.xml**

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:style/Theme">
        <item name="attr/homeIcon">@drawable/ic_home</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
    <application android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

So as you have noticed I am defining a custom attr homeIcon and setting the attribute value in AppTheme.

When I define this attribute in a layout XML and try to access it it works smoothly

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="?attr/homeIcon" />
```

and renders the `Drawable` ic_home in an `ImageView`.

But I am not able to figure out how to access the `Drawable` programmatically.

I tried to do this with a work around, by defining a holder `LayerList Drawable`, which results in resource not found exception:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:drawable="?attr/homeIcon" />
</layer-list>
```

> **Summary**
>   I want to access the `Drawable` defined in a custom defined `Theme` programmatically.

Comment: Please check my answer by [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53884954/5831373).

Answer (score 74, accepted):

I think you can get the Drawable with this code:

```
TypedArray a = getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(R.style.AppTheme, new int[] {R.attr.homeIcon});     
int attributeResourceId = a.getResourceId(0, 0);
Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(attributeResourceId);
a.recycle();
```

Comment: It wokrs, but you should call a.recycle(); after you're done. Also, first parameter in obtainStyledAttributes is optional.

Comment: Well, this may be simplified even more: just `Drawable drawable = a.getDrawable(0);` is enough (where 0 is the index of requeired attribute in new int[] array).

Comment: If you plan to override those attributes in another themes don`t use `R.style.AppTheme` because values will always be taken from this Theme.
 Just use `obtainStyledAttributes(new int[] {R.attr.homeIcon}); ` and then as @AlexSemeniuk  mentioned `a.getDrawable(0)`

Answer (score 14):

Another possible way to do it:

```java
public static int getResIdFromAttribute(final Activity activity,final int attr) {
    if(attr==0)
        return 0;
    final TypedValue typedvalueattr=new TypedValue();
    activity.getTheme().resolveAttribute(attr,typedvalueattr,true);
    return typedvalueattr.resourceId;
}
```

Or in Kotlin:

```
@JvmStatic
fun getResIdFromAttribute(activity: Activity, attr: Int): Int {
    if (attr == 0)
        return 0
    val typedValue = TypedValue()
    activity.theme.resolveAttribute(attr, typedValue, true)
    return typedValue.resourceId
}
```

no need to recycle anything here...

usage:

```
int drawableResId=getResIdFromAttribute(this,R.attr.homeIcon);
Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(drawableResId);
```

Comment: it worked for me.
but why is there no need to recycle?

Comment: @OlumideOyetoke Check the docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/TypedValue.html . There is no recycle function there...

Answer (score 2):

I used below method to get resource id form style attribute. Then it can be used for drawable, string, dimension so on.

```
TypedArray typedArray = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(new int[] { R.attr.attrName });   
int resourceId = typedArray.getResourceId(0, defaultResourceId);
typedArray.recycle();
```

cheers :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using support / design library easier way to get drawables now is -

```
Context.getDrawable(int)
```

or

```
ContextCompat.getDrawable(Context, int)
```

reference - https://plus.google.com/+BenjaminWeiss/posts/M1dYFaobyBM

Answer (score 1):

Here are the results of my investigation, regarding this topic.
If we have `declare-stylable` then we can override those values in themes.

So far the best way that I found how to get them is the following.

```
TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.AppTheme);
a.getDrawable(R.styleable.AppTheme_homeIcon);
```

By using `R.styleable.AppTheme_homeIcon` we are referencing exactly that attribute that we want. For example if we would have few more attributes, then we can reference them as follows:

```
a.getColor(R.styleable.AppTheme_color,defaultValue);
a.getDimension(R.styleable.AppTheme_width,defaultWidth);
```

And if in current theme those attributes were not defined you will get default values and no Exceptions.