# Custom ListView text color not changing according to theme when inside a Viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-theme, custom-lists, textcolor

In my app I am having a `ViewPager` in the main-screen out of which 2 fragments have **custom ListViews**. The app has different themes with different text colors in each theme.

I have implemented all the UI attributes from the XML itself under different themes and is working fine except for the ***TextColor in the custom ListViews inside ViewPager*** which I am controlling from the code.

**Question : How can I control the TextColor from the XMl ?**

I have tried setting the color attributes for the 3 themes as `TextStyle`, `TextAppearence`, `TextColor` etc. But nothing worked while the same code was working when these custom ListViews were not within the ViewPager.

I am not adding any specific codes as I have tried many methods. But as an example, this is the code which I used for setting the TextColor.

```
android:textColor="?attr/listItemContentTextColor"
```

where the attribute is,

```
 <attr name="listItemContentTextColor" format="color" />
```

which is specified in the themes as,

```
<item name="listItemContentTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
```

Is there any way I can control it from the XML itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found the answer to my Question.

I couldn't control it from the XML itself, but I could implement it *dynamically* instead of hardcoding it. **:)**

The problem was only with those **custom listviews within the ViewPager** which was not taking the attributes from the XML. This is how I solved it.

In **/values/attr.xml**

```
 <attr name="listFontColor" format="color" />
```

And in each `Theme`, I set the listFontColor attribute values accordingly.

```
<item name="listFontColor">@android:color/white</item>
```

Instead of checking with each theme in the code, I fetched the current theme and assigned the font color in the code in my `Adapter` like this,

```
//dynamically fetching the theme's list font Color and setting it to textview
TypedArray a = ((MyActivity)context).getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(((MyApplication)(context.getApplicationContext())).getcurrentTheme(), new int[] {R.attr.listFontColor});     
int attributeResourceId = a.getResourceId(0, 0);
listTitle.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(attributeResourceId));
```

Thanks for the [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8794120/1237656) **:)**