# Change Drawable Based on Theme

Tags: android, styles

I've got an image in two different colors, corresponding to two different themes in Android.  I want to use them in my Action Bar.  I want to refer to a drawable for the icon, theme agnostic, but have that drawable reference the light color for the light theme, and the dark color for the light theme.

In the menu:

```
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_attach_existing_picture"
        android:icon="@drawable/buttonface_picture"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/menu_attach_existing_picture">
    </item>
```

Then in the styles I want to have something that maps @drawable/buttonface_picture to @drawable/buttonface_picture_light in the light theme and @drawable/buttonface_picture_dark for the dark theme.

I feel like there's got to be a way, but I'm having trouble finding the syntax.  If it changes anything, I am using ActionBarSherlock.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Seems like I'm always just a Google search or two away from my answers.  The solution is:

in styles.xml

```
<attr name="buttonface_picture" format="reference"/>
```

then in the actual theme:

```
<item name="buttonface_picture">@drawable/buttonface_picture_dark</item>
```

or

```
<item name="buttonface_picture">@drawable/buttonface_picture_light</item>
```

Then, in the menu.xml:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_attach_existing_picture"
    android:icon="?attr/buttonface_picture"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/menu_attach_existing_picture">
</item>
```

The [Accessing Resources Page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html#ReferencesToThemeAttributes) combined with [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6375804/theme-styles-and-alias-nesting-not-working) eventually got it to click in my brain.

Comment: How about making it programmatically?

Comment: That particular answer gives an example of attr -> R identifier -> dimension. You'll have to instead use that identifier to access a drawable

Comment: @AlexS try `drawable.applyTheme(view.context.theme)`