# Android Theme drawable doesn't work with Color Drawable (Bug?)

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, themes

So I'm trying to make a `selector` that uses a theme-based color as its background. Following the instructions from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13735919/1852456), I first define my color drawable in res/values/colors.xml:

```
<color name="selected">#FFF7C9</color>
```

Then I define an attribute in res/values/attrs.xml:

```
<attr name="drawable_selected" format="reference" />
```

and then in my theme, I set attribute to my color drawable (res/values/styles.xml):

```
<style name="AppThemeWhite" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="drawable_selected">@color/selected</item>
</style>
```

finally, I reference the attribute in my selector (res/drawable/selected_background):

```
<selector>
    <item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="?drawable_selected" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

When I run this, I get an error `Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>` when trying to inflate the class that uses the selector. However, when I change the selector's `state_activated` to reference the drawable directly using `android:drawable="@color/selected"`, it works.

Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

**EDIT**

If I add a color attribute (res/values/attrs.xml)

```
<attr name="selected_color" format="color" />
```

and define the color in my theme (res/values/styles.xml)

```
<item name="selected_color">#FFF7C9</item>
```

I can change the color drawable to change based on them (res/values/colors.xml)

```
<color name="selected">?selected_color</color>
```

and reference the drawable directly using `android:drawable="@color/selected` in my selector.
However, this causes a crash as well! And changing the color drawable back to a hardcoded value of `#FFF7C9` fixes it. It seems this whole theming system is pretty broken...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Reason

Yeah, referencing custom theme attributes from drawable (or colors) doesn't work on Android currently.

Here you can see more details about the issue that was reported long time ago: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=26251

As you can see they have finally resolved it in Android L release, but anywhere lower than L such referencing will fail.

### Solution

To work around this issue you need to do something like that:

```
<selector>
    <item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@color/selected" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

where `@color/selected` is defined as at the beginning of your post:

```
<color name="selected">#FFF7C9</color>
```

Comment: I tried this in L preview though...maybe only in the official release?

Comment: I cannot test it myself now so I can only see what is said on their issue tracker. But it doesn't matter if it's fixed or not - you probably don't want to relay on it (unless you want to target your app on L only). Please just use the workaround.

Comment: Yea I already used this workaround, I was just asking to see if anybody else was facing the same issues, and if I should ask to reopen the issue report. Thanks for all the help tho!

Comment: @woojoo666 If you want reopen that issue you should test it on L-preview with the project provided in second comment. I have proposed the solution because you didn't mention that you already use this workaround. Btw. What answer to this question you are looking for? I've confirmed you that this is a known issue, provided related issue in Android bug tracker and proposed working workaround. Did I misunderstand the question at any point? Please tell me so I could update my answer if it's not appropriate.

Comment: Sorry I was still researching the issue, I'll mark this as the answer now lol

Comment: Ah OK, I just thought that you want some more details or anything like that - so just asked:)

Comment: I do not understand the solution mentioned in the post. It isn't solution or workaround to support theme based colour referencing. However, the reason mentioned does have supporting facts.