# Setting theme colors in drawable pre-lollipop?

Tags: android

I've been using theme attributes in all my drawables, but I found out that this is not supported pre-21

Is there a method I can use to use

```
<shape android:shape="rectangle"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="?attr/background_1" />
<corners android:radius="@dimen/button_corner_radius" />
```

And such drawables in my layouts? Thanks a lot. Not sure what to do now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it from the xml file. As you can see in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13735919), you have to create as many different resource files as background colours you want to use. In your case, if we call your file shape_drawable.xml:

in styles.xml

```
<attr name="shape_drawable" format="reference"/>
```

then in the actual themes:

```
// Theme X
<item name="shape_drawable">@drawable/shape_drawable_x</item>
// Theme Y
<item name="shape_drawable">@drawable/shape_drawable_y</item>
```

where shape_drawable_x would use solid color x and shape_drawable_y would use solid color y.

Then, in the place where you actually use the drawable:

```
android:src="?attr/shape_drawable"
```

Comment: Thanks, I figured this out, but I forgot to close it